# Is there a minimum constant velocity an object has to travel at to collide with a projectile?

Tags: kinematics, projectile

Note: this is assuming that $B$ is shot at the same time that $A$ is at $h$ if that was not clear.

I have been working through projectile motion in physics class, and I have been wondering if you had some projectile $A$ moving at some constant speed, if it was travelling really slow, could it still collide with a projectile launched from the ground ($B$)? Does $A$ have to have some minimum velocity to impact $B$, or does it not matter? I'm pretty sure that $A$ has some maximum constant velocity, but I'm not sure if there exists some minimum or not.

I think there might be since if $A$ is travelling really slow, then $B$ would have to be shot almost directly upwards to hit $A$, but I am not certain.

This is what I had in mind:
[image]

Comment: Projectiles collide with stationary objects all the time. Are there other constraints to your problem that you haven't shared? Like h > 0, for example?

Comment: A is travelling with constant velocity vA where vA > 0. A is located at a height y=h directly above. Projectile B is launched with velocity (vBcosθ, vBsinθ) when A is directly overhead (same starting time). That is about as specific as I can think to make it. h would be greater than zero as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  As mentioned by R.W.Bird, to collide they must both have the same component of velocity in the $x$ direction.

For the $y$ direction, to collide:

$$v_{Ay}t+h = v_{By}t-\frac{gt^2}{2}$$

make a quadratic $at^2+bt +c=0$ and then try discriminant $b^2 - 4ac\gt 0$ to see if there is a valid solution, etc...all the best with it

Comment: would I have to worry about the x and y components of the object travelling at constant velocity, or does that only apply to the projectile B? A is travelling with constant velocity vA where vA > 0. They are both not projectiles in a parabolic arc, only one of them is, the other (object A) has no acceleration.

Comment: @Curulian, yes the minimum $v_{By}$ is found from the equation above (that includes $v_{Ay}$).  for the x component $v_{Bx} = v_{Ax}$, over to you now, all the best

Answer (score 0):

In your sketch, both objects are projectiles. Neither has a constant velocity. If they were to collide after being fired simultaneously from the y axis, they must both have the same horizontal component of velocity.  The vertical velocity of (A) would have to be selected to bring it to a collision point. That would lie between a minimum and maximum value, but might catch (B) going up or coming down.

Comment: A is just an object travelling overhead with some constant velocity Va. Both are launched when object A is h meters above B. I.e. object A is travelling in the +x direction with speed Va >0.